# No puedo conectarme a sql server instalado en ubuntu?

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, cmd

Que tal buenas tardes estoy experimentando problemas al conectarme desde ssms a mi instancia virtual que he creado desde google cloud, la base de datos es sql server, he creado un usuario especifico con todos los accesos, configure los puertos tcp y udp en el 1433 y 1434, entre el ssms config para que pueda escuchar cualquier tipo de ip a aun nada, a su ves cree reglas en el google cloud y no obtendo respuesta, como deberia solucionar este tema agradesco de antemano tu respuesta.

He intentado todo lo que ha estado a mi alcanse pero tampoco encontre mucha informacion.

Comment: Primero, te puedo decir que la pregunta no es apropiada para el sitio. Aquí se tratan temas de programación. Segundo, te recomendaría que verifiques paso a paso.... es decir, capa a capa, que el servicio esté funcionando. Normalmente eso significa: - verificar que el puerto esté abierto (con `netstat`, por ejemplo), arrancar un sniffer y ver que cuando tu _crees_ que le está llegando tráfico, el sniffer lo capture (primero con un telnet simple, luego con un cliente de verdad).... y así sucesivamente, uno va descartando posibles problemas uno a uno.